# What is the role and mechanism of "cost" in bcrypt?

Tags: php, hash

I have been trying to use bcrypt using PHP. I searched on google and got some code which I used in my project, successfully done but don't understand what is the use and mechanism of "cost" in bcrypt. Can anybody assist me how cost works on bcrypt? Or may be the whole mechanism of bcrpyt theoretically?

Comment: Do read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php it's all in there. *"cost - which denotes the algorithmic cost that should be used. Examples of these values can be found on the [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) page."*

Comment: As @Fred-ii- said, do your research, and don't expect us to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the cost factor you can control the time which is necessary to calculate a single hash. With fast algorithms like MD5 it is possible to calculate about [100 Giga hashes per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance), what makes brute-forcing ways too easy.

So we do rounds of hashing and the cost factor describes how many rounds are done. For more detailed information you can have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php), the cost factor is described on the BCrypt page.

Comment: Thank you very much and really appreciate. Your tutorial was fruitful.